# Add class for each individual div on hover in only javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, events, listener

I'm trying to add a class `.active` to each `div` on hover that is nested under a parent div. I wrote a very complicated way to add a class, but the problem is it's adding it to *all* of my divs, instead of the one that is being hovered.

Here is the JS:

```
var carouselItems = document.getElementsByClassName("carouselItem")

for (var i = 0; i < carouselItems.length; i++) {
    if (carouselItems.length) {
        carouselItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function makeActive() {
            for (var j = 0; j < carouselItems.length; ++j) {
                carouselItems[j].classList.add("active")
            }
        }, true)
    }
}
```

I have four nested divs and it's adding the class "active" to each one of them regardless of whichever one you hover over. I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a bit confusing not having a sample of your HTML to refer to, but anyway: are you familiar with the **`this`** keyword?

Comment: `this.classList.add("active")`

Comment: Ah that works.. thank you both! :)